# Programmatically check authenticoded files in NuGet Package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, signing, authenticode

Is there a way to check a dll file inside a NuGet package when installing it using NuGet API.

Scenario:

I want a c#/.net application to be able to update itself at runtime using NuGet packages. Since this is obviously pretty risky I would like to verify that the package comes from the source I expect it to come from.

Problem:

NuGet does not support package signing. There is a paper addressing the issue here: https://blog.nuget.org/20150203/package-signing.html

What I have done so far:

1. Build an empty project
2. Sign the dll file (signtool sign /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /a ".\app.dll")
3. Create a NuGet package from it (nuget spec add.dll, nuget pack .\app.dll.nuspec)

The dll file inside the NuGet package is now signed and I can upload it to a NuGet repo.

This is my application code:

```
public static void installPackage(string packageId, string connectionString, string path){
        IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(connectionString);

        PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, path);

        packageManager.InstallPackage(packageId);
    }
```

The example is taken from here:

https://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html

The only possible solution I can imagine at the moment would be to use a download package function from the NuGet API, unpack the downloaded package, do the check and install afterwards. Sadly I can not find any hint in the API that the install process could be done in those two steps.

Alternatively, I could use PGP to create a detached signature, sign the NuGet package itself and do a check on the NuGet package with the detached signature. However, that leads to the same problem of first being able to download the package.

I would be grateful for any hint! Thank you.

--- Update ---

I think I have found a way to use NuGet and PGP signing for package verification. I am doing the following:

1. Get list of available NuGets from NuGet Server (I am using Nexus)
2. Mark a file for installation
3. The Package provides a download link:

   ```
   IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(<connectionString>);

   DataServicePackage package = (DataServicePackage) repo.FindPackage(packageId);
   String downloadUrl = package.DownloadUrl.AbsoluteUri;
   ```
4. Download the package and store on disk:

```cs
using (var client = new WebClient()){
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<User>, <Pass>);
    var content = client.DownloadData(downloadUrl);
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(content)){
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(<pathToLocalRepo>, FileMode.CreateNew);
        memoryStream.CopyTo(fs);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

5. Download the detached signature from a different server
6. Verify the detached signature and the downloaded nupkg (I used BouncyCastle)
7. If verification succeeds:
8. Use the directory the file is stored as new repository and install the package from there

```cs
//Initialize local repository
string path = <pathToLocalRepo>;
IPackageRepository localRepo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(path);
var packages = repo.GetPackages();
//Initialize the package manager
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(localRepo, path);
//Install
packageManager.InstallPackage(<packageId>);
```

Using this approach still leaves you with the possibility to authenticode the files inside the NuGet package.

Happy to hear what you guys think about this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checking the dlls inside a package may not be the safest option as a malicious file can be added the package which can compromise your intent/machine. The NuGet team is working on allowing author signing for packages. In that process you will have `NuGet.exe sign <package>` and `NuGet.exe verify <package>` commands. You can read more about it the [the blog post](https://blog.nuget.org/20170914/NuGet-Package-Signing.html). The detailed specs are at - [Sign Command](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/NuGet-Sign-Command) and [Verify Command](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/NuGet-Verify-Command).

---

Update - 
NuGet team has finished implementing package signing and verification. You can now sign a package, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/sign-a-package) and verify the integrity of a package (among other things) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-verify).

You can read about the technical specifications [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Package-Signatures-Technical-Details).

Comment: Your blog post link is pointing to a 404. However, I have read, that there is a plan to implement package signing with asp.net 5 - That still leaves the question what to do in between.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. i have updated the blog post link.